# Possible to use Rails with no HTML? (Just Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax

I'm a Rails beginner messing around with a super simple app.

What I'm wondering is whether you can use Rails strictly with the Ruby language and forget HTML all together.

Why I'm asking:

In my */testapp/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb* file, (which is my homepage), I tested it with the code:

```
puts "Hello World!"
```

When I navigate to the page using the rails server the text includes the *puts*. I even changed the file name to /testapp/app/views/welcome/*index.rb* (omitting the html), it didn't work.

Can I use Ruby like this? Or do I need to modify something within Rails to use Ruby like this?  I don't get it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In erb, you must put code in `<% %>` tags, otherwise it isn't treated as ruby.  Broadly, you don't need to write any direct HTML, but you will of course need to write in a templating language (erb or haml), which compiles to HTML.

Comment: Keep in mind that Rails is a WEB framework and as such, it involve HTML =)

Comment: Rails is primarily a framework for database access, not just for HTML. ERB can be used with any language, not just HTML.

Comment: You could just write a [`CGI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/HtmlExtension.html) in pure ruby but you would need to know `HTML` to format everything correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be learning Rails you will need to do it in conjunction with HTML. When I learned I started with ERB and then moved to [Haml](http://haml.info/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the page to just show static text you can put `Hello World!` right in the `index.html.erb` file.

Mostly though, you'll use these views to dynamically create web pages for you.  That way if your website is storing books and users continue to add more books to the website, your index page will automatically include all the books everyone entered.  In your `index.html.erb` that code would look something like:

```
<tbody>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= book.title %></td>
      <td><%= book.body %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', (edit_book_path(book)+"/hello?") %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I highly suggest running in your console:

```
rails generate scaffold books title:string author:string
```

Run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Fire up your server and go to `localhost:3000/books`

This should give you a visual example of what I'm talking about and then you can walk through the code to help you understand what Rails is doing.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I'm going to try generating the books scaffolding.